# dojo comobox popup menu width too large

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I am making a dojo widget with a combo box. But for some reason the dropdown of the combo box is always at 100% of my body element.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="width: 30%;">
  <div data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory"
data-dojo-id="stateStore"
data-dojo-props="data: [{id: 'y', name: 'yes'}, {id: 'n', name: 'no'}]">
  </div>
  <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"
data-dojo-props="hasDownArrow:false, store:stateStore, searchAttr:'name'"
name="state" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the width of the dropdown to be the same width as the textbox itself by using the property called `forceWidth`. To change the form of the combobox you should try to use the `style` property.

Information of it can be found at the [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/ComboBox).

For your example I would use:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" data-dojo-props="hasDownArrow:false, store:stateStore, searchAttr:'name', forceWidth: true, style: { width: '100%' }" name="state" />
```

And the JSFiddle I used to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/smF2C/

Comment: Works with dijit/form/FilteringSelect too.